# Fatal Error when trying to log in DRUPAL

Tags: 7, installation

My `Drupal 7` website is throwing `500 internal server error`, when I try to log in as Admin.

I checked the apache error log it throws below error

```
 PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/*****/******/sites/all/modules/context/context_ui/export_ui/context.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /******/******/sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/plugins.inc on line 480, referer: http://*******/user
```

What could be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: is [context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) present in `sites/all/modules` folder ?

Comment: @shrish is right - is this file present? With proper permissions? What have you changed before this started?..

Comment: i have not changed it .... it works in my local but in my dev environment server it is not working

Comment: try installing `context module` again, may be some file is missing while copying.

Comment: ok, let me try. but it works in my local but not in my dev server

Comment: Just try by  removing the context module from module directory

Comment: it may seems funny answer but this is what I did.... I went in database searched for context module [since in my module folder i did not have context module directory, it should not be in db but it was there] and found 2-3 context module search, status as 1 , I made status to 0 and clear all cache from db by truncating cache tables --- not sure how but it fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm which version of php you are using? I just realized that the magic php constant "**DIR**" (which I first used here in beta4) may only work in php versions 5.3 or greater, so I'm guessing you have a version that's below v5.3.

According to the Drupal requirements, the PHP requirement for Drupal 7 is "PHP 5.2.5 or higher (5.3 recommended)", So I may have made a mistake by introducing a construct that's not compatible with some php versions that Drupal 7 still supports. I'll need to fix this, but either way if you can confirm your php version that would be very helpfu